# What is my lambda here

Tags: self-study, survival, exponential-distribution

The life of automobile voltage regulators has an exponential distribution with a mean life of six years. You purchase a six-year-old automobile, with a working voltage regulator and plan to own it for six years.

What is the probability that the voltage regulator fails during your ownership?

Is my $\lambda = 2$ because after 12 total years you expect 2 failures? That's what my gut tells me, as setting the $\lambda=1$ would suggest that the next 6 years during ownership are as statistically healthy as a brand new regulator. It's the fact that you're looking at only the last 6 years that's making me question myself.

Comment: You're asking about a variable, $\lambda$ that you haven't defined. Is it supposed to be the mean or the rate parameter of the exponential distribution, or something else?

Comment: The memorylessness of the exponential means it doesn't matter how long the thing existed before, if it's alive at the start of this period, it's exactly as if it were new.

Answer (score 8):

The probability that the lifetime $T$ of a voltage regulator with mean lifetime $\mu$ exceeds six years from the date of manufacture ($t=0$)  is

$$\Pr(T>6) = \exp{\frac{-6}{\mu}}$$

The probability that its lifetime exceeds twelve years given that it's already lasted six years is

$$\Pr(T>12 \mid T>6)$$

Re-write the conditional probability as the ratio of a joint to a  marginal probability, & note that the joint probability simplifies (if a lifetime's over twelve years it's necessarily over six):

$$\Pr(T>12 \mid T>6) = \frac{\Pr(T>12, T>6)}{\Pr(T>6)}\\
=\frac{\Pr(T>12)}{\Pr(T>6)}$$

Compare the answer you get to this with the first probability you calculated, then read up on the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. Does it seem like a reasonable assumption for the distribution of voltage regulator lifetimes?

Comment: Does the memoryless property still hold when it's a part that wears out over time? You assume that P(T>12) and P(T>6) are independent, but can't you say that if a product is at least 6 years old then it has 6 years of wear? or am I trying to put too much "real world" in this simple word problem.

Comment: The question says the failure time is exponentially distributed, which implies memorylessness. In the real world you'd certainly check that assumption or start with a more flexible assumed distribution, typically a Weibull in reliability analysis. Even in exams it's often worth pointing out which assumptions are particularly shaky. (BTW I didn't assume $\Pr(T > 12)$ & $\Pr(T > 6)$ are probabilities of independent events: quite the contrary; the former implies the latter.)

Answer (score 1):

The exponential distribution has a mean that is somewhat "before" the 50%-tile of its associated survival curve. Because of the memoryless property, the probability of survival to 12 years is  <strike>exactly one-half</strike> the probability of survival to 6 years squared. The probability of failure to any time is 1-Pr_survival.

If you are only talking about one item then the number of expected failures cannot exceed 1, unless of course, you replace it with an identical item. The rate, lambda is not the inverse of the expected number of failures but it is the inverse of the mean lifetime. So lambda is 1/6 and :

```
> exp(-1)  # the expected survival of one unit at 6 years: exp(-t/lambda)
[1] 0.3678794
```

If these are "dieing" at this rate, then the number of needed regulators to time T is distributed as a Poisson variate.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive at this statement: "*the probability of survival to 12 years is exactly one-half the probability of survival to 6 years.*" ? I believe that it's not correct. Scortchi's prior answer is correct, and allows us to compute the relationship between the two fairly readily (as does your own mention of the memorylessness property)

Comment: I take it back. It would only be 1/2 if the survival at T=6 were 0.5 (and I've already said that wasn't the case, so I'm hoist on my own petard.) The survival at T=12 is (0.3678794)^2.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's the square of the one at 6.